# How do you take a screenshot in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013, origin

How can I take a screenshot?

When I press Print Screen to take a screenshot while in the game, the image on my clipboard is the Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shortcut key 'C' takes a screenshot shortcut key 'V' makes a video.

All hotkeys:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I forgot all about the shortcut insert that came with the game.